# Having a Windows scheduled task to emulate cron

Tags: windows, ssh, cron

I'm trying to rig up a really ghetto cron job. I'm hosting a site on shared hosting (can't afford dedicated), and I need to use cron for some stuff on it. The problem is obviously cron stuff is not allowed. The possible solution is: my Windows computer is always on.

My question is: what would be the best way to write a script to automatically run commands on the server (which is a Linux server)? Are there any good Windows programs out there that will connect to the server and run the needed commands from a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming when you mean "run commands on the server," you have SSH/Telnet access, Putty can do this.

```
putty.exe [-ssh | -telnet] [user@]host -m C:/Scripts/MyRemoteScript.txt
```

It will run the remote script and close the PuTTY window.

You can schedule this process and it should run on a regular basis.  I suggest using RSA authentication / Auto login with this in a saved session.